# MATLAB: populate cell array and format number

Tags: string, matlab

What's the efficient way to populate a cell array with values from a vector (each formatted differently).

For example:

```
V = [12.3 .004 3 4.222];
```

Desired cell array:

```
array = {'A = 12.30' 'B = 0.004' 'C = 3' 'D = 4'};
```

Is there an easier way than calling `sprintf` for each and every cell?

```
array = {sprintf('A = %.2f',V(1)) sprintf('B = %.3f',V(2)) ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no vectorized form of `sprintf` that supports different formats, so you're mostly stuck with a `sprintf` call per cell. But you could arrange the code to be easier to deal with in a loop.

```
V = [12.3 .004 3 4.222];
names = num2cell('A':'Z');
formats = { '%.2f' '%.3f' '%d' '%.0f' };

c = cell(size(V));
for i = numel(V)
    c{i} = sprintf(['%s = ' formats{i}], names{i}, V(i));
end
```

It would be tricky to get anything faster than the naive way without dropping down to Java or C, because it's still going to take a `sprintf()` call for each cell, and that's going to dominate the execution time.

If you have a large number of elements and a relatively small number of formats, you could use unique() to group them up in to one sprintf() call per format, using the vectorized version of sprintf and then splitting on a delimiter to get individual strings. That may or may not be faster, depending on your exact data set and implementation.

Or you could write a MEX file that pushes the loop down in to C, looping over a call to C's sprintf. That would be faster, once you get up to moderately large input sizes.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done as follows:

```
V = [12.3 .004 3 4.222];
names = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
array = strcat(names(:), ' = ', ...
    strtrim(mat2cell(num2str(V(:), '%.4f'), ones(1,numel(V))))).';
```

How this works:

- `num2str` gives a char matrix, using a format specifier (you may want to change the one I used).
- `mat2cell`  converts that into a cell array, putting each row into a cell.
- `strtrim` removes spaces.
- `strcat` concatenates cell-wise.

Comment: I always forget about `strtrim`.  Very useful!